# Which Expression product is for Silverlight developers?

Tags: silverlight, ide

I'm not a graphics person, but I want to learn silverlight development.

Which expression product am I looking at here?  Blend or studio or is vs.net 2008 all I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [studio](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Overview.aspx?key=studio) as a whole is great and you can also do stuff with VS but you are probably looking for [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Overview.aspx?key=blend).

Answer (score 0):

Blend is the product I've been using for silverlight.  You can work with just visual studio 2008, but Bend can make the vector graphics much easier to make.

Answer (score 0):

For the developer side of silverlight Visual Studio is all you need. For the designer side Expression Blend is what you will want.

Basically the visusl studio designer is read only meaning you have to write all the xaml by hand, blend gives you the ability to drag drop components and generally make creating the UI easier. (When compared to hand coding XAML)